# Data Warehouse é Orientado a Transação ou a Consulta?

Tags: banco-de-dados, data-warehouse

## Contexto do Problema

Lendo sobre o assunto *Data Warehouse*, tirei algumas conclusões distintas sobre o que afirma o livro texto.

> #### Observe o que o autor explica em relação a DW orientado a transação:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo que o autor afirma que os *DW* são orientados a transação.

> #### Agora veja o que ele diz no parágrado seguinte:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo em seguida ele afirma que os DW **não são orientados a transações** de rotina, o que me deixou um pouco confuso, já que ele está negando.

## Meus Entendimentos

1. Ao ler sobre o assunto entendi que os DW são ferramentas de apoio a decisão e que são **orientados a consultas**.
2. Entendi que por serem focados nas consultas, o banco **pode não respeitar** as tão conhecidas formas normais (1FN,2FN,3FN), já que elas **aumentam** a quantidade de relações e **diminuem** a chance de duplicação.
3. O fato é que o **aumento de relações** no banco **afeta o desempenho** das consultas por causa dos diversos ´JOIN´ que são constantemente realizados.
4. Os DW costumam ser bem grandes já que ele serve de repositório central de todos os outros bancos de dados.
5. Banco de dados transacionais (Convencionais) estão preocupados com a **não duplicação** de registro, dessa forma, tendem a respeitar as formas normais. Podendo ser chamados de bancos **orientados a transação**.
6. Os dados armazenados no DW possuem característica **NÃO volátil**, significa dizer que na etapa de carregamento, os dados são filtrados e limpos, após essa etapa os dados **somente** sofrem **operações** de **consultas** e **exclusões**, `sem que possam ser alterados`, essa característica representa a **não volatilidade**.

## Dúvida

Meus entendimentos sobre o assunto estão corretos? A comunidade concorda total ou parcialmente com as sentenças enumeradas acima?

> Lembrando que o principal foco da pergunta está no título, ou seja, posso considerar de fato que os DW são orientados a consulta?

Fonte: Sistemas de Banco de dados 6ª edição, autores: Elmasri, Ramez Navathe, Shamkant B. Ano: 2011 Cap 29, pg 720

Answer (score 0):

Achei o primeiro fragmento meio curto, vale lembrar outra caracteristica importante de DW que os dados praticamente não sofrem (nem deve) alterações para não interferir no resultado da analise e registros novos são adicionados periodicamente via lote (ETL).

Transações são usadas mais em operações de escrita onde é importante concluir todas as alterações com sucesso ou cancelar tudo e voltar para o estado (válido) anterior.

Comment: Eu tomei nota dessa caracteristicas de dados não volátil, eu esqueci de colocar como item da pergunta (na parte meus entendimento), se quiser posso por. O que acha?

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante pode é importante esse detalhe.

Comment: veja se ficou melhor

Comment: O trecho que eu recortei foi só pra destacar o conceito escrito pelo o autor do livro, esse parágrafo é muito extenso, da quase a metade de uma página do pdf.